# Android how to prevent scrollview's content jump when resize scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a layout like this:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TabHidden"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_detail_tab1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
    >
        ...
</TableRow>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewGameDetail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/Tab"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_detail_tab1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
    >
        ...
    </TableRow>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

When I scroll the ScrollView to top of the screen, I will hide the TableRow inside ScrollView and show the TableRow outside by calling

```
tabHidden.setVisibility(TableRow.VISIBLE);
tab.setVisibility(TableRow.GONE);
```

That will make the TableRow outside ScrollView always on top of the screen. It works fine except when TableRow inside is hiding, all contents inside ScrollView will be pushed up a bit (equal the height of TableRow). I don't want it jump up like that because scroll action will not look smooth. Is there anyway to prevent the ScrollView contents auto fill the blank space like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setVisibility(View.GONE);` It will be completely removed, what you want to do in order to leave the empty space there, is to use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: I've already try this. It's true in some way but not in my case unfortunately. But I will set this as answer since my problem is quite complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, if you have anything in mind just write it here and I'll try to help you.